# convert one column to json

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-server

Using Azure SQLServer I'm trying to convert only one column to json format. The data is in a nvarchar field.  Using `For Json Auto` will convert all fields and all rows. What I need is just to convert only one column.

By converting to json what I mean is to be clickable to see it's data a new window inside SSMS.

Let's say the table (Logs) has 2 columns: `LogId` and `LogData`. `LogData` is `nvarchar(max)` and contains json data.

What I need is to query the table and have a clickable `logData` column.

Comment: `FOR JSON` will just show the results of the columns and rows you are selecting. You probably have a `*` on the column list. Add a new column of JSON type and do an UPDATE to set it's value, then drop the old column.

Comment: Thanks @EzLo FOR JSON gives me just one json for all columns and rows. I'm looking for a way to just somehow convert one column.

Comment: Sample data and desired results can really help understand the question. Json is not a type, it's a serialization format - `nvarchar` can contain whatever string you want, formatted as Json or not. Please [edit] your question to include the relevant table DDL + some DML for sample data as well as desired results.

Comment: thanks @ZoharPeled. I added more info

Comment: What do you mean by `clickable`? where do you run the query?

Comment: @ZoharPeled, this is for SSMS.
when we have json in the result grid which is a json instead of simple text it become a link and by clicking on it it will open a new window and display the json in that window. 
The main goal that I want to achieve here is to not copy and paste the json column into notepad to check it.

Answer (score 10):

You can try like following to get only one column as `JSON`

```
select o.*,
 (select YourColumnForJson  
    from YourTable i 
        where o.Identifer=i.Identifer for json auto) as JsonColumn 
 from YourTable o
```